# Get all from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

sorry for my bad explanation if it's the case.

I have a WebAPI and i need to return all the Artist in my database.

My code is the follow:

**ArtistRepository.cs:**

```
public class ArtistRepository: IDisposable
{
    private WhereIsMyBandContext context;

    public ArtistRepository(WhereIsMyBandContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Artist> GetAllArtists()
    {
        return context.Artists.ToList();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**ArtistController.cs:**

```
public class ArtistsController : ApiController
{
    public ArtistRepository repository = new ArtistRepository(new WhereIsMyBandContext());

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Artist> Get()
    {
        return repository.GetAllArtists();
    }
}
```

**Program.cs: (*My entry point*)**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57026/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            var response = webClient.DownloadString("http://localhost:57026/api/Artists");
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The return I get is always this: [] and my database is populated.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Without seeing all of your code and your DB it's unfortunately impossible to answer your question. I'd advise you to attach the debugger to `w3wp.exe` and put a break point on ArtistController's Get(). Step through and see what is causing the list to get populated from your database incorrectly.

Comment: Are you sure the connection string is correct?

Comment: @DavidG yes. The connection string is right.

Comment: I don't see where the connection string is being passed into the context here. Can you confirm that your repository is getting actual records?

Comment: why did you create the `client` object?